# Create Table - Oracle APEX Error: What is causing the errors in my CREATE TABLE sql script?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, create-table

I am receiving errors when creating tables for DIRECTOR, COMPANY, and GENRE. MOVIE runs fine and I included it because it is the PK.
DIRECTOR Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
GENRE and COMPANY Error: ora-00904 invalid identifier

I am stuck so anything will help. Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE (
IMDB_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
YearCreated VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
MovieDuration NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
Mean_Rating NUMBER(2,1) NOT NULL,
Number_of_Votes VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
Budget VARCHAR(11),
CONSTRAINT IMDB_PK PRIMARY KEY (IMDB_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DIRECTOR (
DirectorID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
DirectorFirst VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DirectorMiddle VARCHAR(20),
DirectorLast VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
WriterFirst VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
WriterMiddle VARCHAR(20),
WriterLast VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT IMDB_PK PRIMARY KEY (IMDB_ID),
CONSTRAINT DIRECTOR_FK FOREIGN KEY(DirectorID)
);

CREATE TABLE COMPANY (
Production_Company VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT IMDB_PK PRIMARY KEY (IMDB_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE GENRE (
Genre_1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Genre_2 VARCHAR(15),
Genre_3 VARCHAR(15),
CONSTRAINT IMDB_PK PRIMARY KEY (IMDB_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

in company , genre and DIRECTOR table , you are saying make a primary key on IMDB_ID column , which that column doesn't exists in neither of those tables, so you have to add them first .

however I guess based on the design , imdb_id is actually foreign key in those tables referenced to movie table

Answer (score 0):

You can't name ALL your primary keys `IMDB_PK`; Oracle won't allow it as those names have to be unique.

Besides, you tried to create a foreign key constraint which points to *nowhere* - get rid of it.

Fixed, your code might look like this (I'm not saying that this is what you really want, but - based on what you posted so far - might be a good starting point).

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE movie
  2  (
  3     imdb_id           CHAR (9) NOT NULL,
  4     title             VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  5     yearcreated       VARCHAR (8) NOT NULL,
  6     movieduration     NUMBER (5) NOT NULL,
  7     mean_rating       NUMBER (2, 1) NOT NULL,
  8     number_of_votes   VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
  9     budget            VARCHAR (11),
 10     CONSTRAINT imdb_pk PRIMARY KEY (imdb_id)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE director
  2  (
  3     directorid       CHAR (9) NOT NULL,
  4     directorfirst    VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  5     directormiddle   VARCHAR (20),
  6     directorlast     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  7     writerfirst      VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  8     writermiddle     VARCHAR (20),
  9     writerlast       VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 10     CONSTRAINT director_fk PRIMARY KEY (directorid)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE company
  2  (
  3     production_company   VARCHAR (50),
  4     CONSTRAINT company_pk PRIMARY KEY (production_company)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE genre
  2  (
  3     genre_1   VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
  4     genre_2   VARCHAR (15),
  5     genre_3   VARCHAR (15),
  6     CONSTRAINT genre_pk PRIMARY KEY (genre_1)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
```